# Why does my variable keep getting emptied on page refresh?

Tags: javascript

I'm really a beginner with javascript, but I've been trying to solve the issue below and can't figure it out. Hope anyone can enlighten me.

I try to parse an userID from one website to another by embedding the ID in a url param (/?UID=213), then reading it out and storing it in a javascript variable on the destination website.

```
//store any userID parsed from the webshop
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const userID = urlParams.get('UID');
console.log("userID: " + userID);
```

Initially this works fine. However, when I browse between pages on the destination website the UID keeps being emptied. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Whenever you navigate to a new page, everything from the previous view is lost.

Comment: Just browsing does not carry over URL queries from one page to another. The links would have to _specifically_ be written to include them. What you can do though is, if there is a UID in the url, copy that into either localStorage (accessible in any tab for the same website) or sessionStorage (accessible only in the same tab for the same website), and then have pages look in those if there is UID in the URL.

Comment: To be clear, there are facilities for saving values at the browser (the Storage API and its implementations).

Comment: You're almost certainly looking for [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API) — and, by the way, you can simplify that code to `const userId = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get("UID")`

Comment: I thought javascript const variables were global and carry over from page to page. But seems I was wrong. I'll have a look at the sessionStorage. Thanks.